# PHP: Good way to reconstruct associative array from base64_decode

Tags: php, arrays, url, encode

I want to `base64_encode` the parameters I send over the url.

**Send:**

```
<?php 
    $product = array("productID"=>"13776", "name"=>"something", "availability"=>"1000");
    $url_details = "?id=" . base64_encode(http_build_query($product));
?>

<a href="details.php<?php echo $url_details; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">Details</a>
```

**Receive:**

```
<?php
    $details = base64_decode($_GET["id"]);
    // $product = what is the best way to reconstruct the array from $details?
?>
<p>
    Name: <?php echo $products["name"]; ?>
    ...
</p>
```

The encoding destroys the array, is there a convenient way to make an associative array out of the string again?

(the encoded url is not sensitive information, but I still do not want it to be flat out readable in the url. If there is a better way to pass this data between pages than what I am doing, let me know)

Comment: [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) is the inverse of http_build_query.

Comment: if I `parse_str(base64_decode($_GET["id"]);` I get nothing though?

Comment: Read the documentation. Pay special attention to the warning. parse_str is a mess. You probably want the two-argument form of parse_str.

Comment: Do I have to be careful for malicious code too, like in the solution posted below? I haven't seen a warning in the documentation. If not, this is a much more straight forward solution.

Comment: parse_str will not execute arbitrary code, if that's what you're asking. Again, I can only point you to the docs and the examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) is the inverse of http_build_query, so to recover your data:

```
parse_str(base64_decode($_GET["id"]), $details);
```

Note that parse_str is harmful if called with only one argument.

And as an aside, you may not want to put this kind of information into the URL to begin with, since it can be easily disclosed to third parties, [via the Referrer header](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2015/01/healthcare.gov-sends-personal-data), for instance.

Comment: I agree with Peter here, this is probably a better solution for you since you already had `http_build_query()` and there's no risk of code execution. Still, make sure to check you're getting the array you're expecting since it can still be modified.

Answer (score 3):

You can [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) your array:

```
<?php
$product = array("productID"=>"13776", "name"=>"something", "availability"=>"1000");
$url_details = base64_encode(serialize($product));
```

And then, on your end page [unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it:

```
<?php
$details = unserialize(base64_decode($url_details));
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/PDXZP)

**However** you need to be careful and do thorough checking of what you're receiving, since `unserialize()` will **execute** arbitrary code sent by the client. For example, I can `serialize()` my own `array`, then `base64_encode()` it, and pass it to the URL in the `id` parameter, and I can do pretty nasty stuff. So definitely check what you're getting in the request!

From the manual:

> ### Warning
>
> Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize() regardless of the
>   options value of allowed_classes. Unserialization can result in code
>   being loaded and executed due to object instantiation and autoloading,
>   and a malicious user may be able to exploit this. Use a safe, standard
>   data interchange format such as JSON (via json_decode() and
>   json_encode()) if you need to pass serialized data to the user.

[Here's](https://www.notsosecure.com/remote-code-execution-via-php-unserialize/) a comprehensive article on the matter. Give it a read!

As the manual says, you can also probably accomplish what you're trying to do with [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), though the same warning remains, **check** that what you're getting is what you're supposed to get and sanitize it.