# How to go from base64_decode() to an array in PHP?

Tags: php

I am passing a base64 encoded string from my javascript (that part works fine) via AJAX. Upon receiving it I do the following:

```
if(!empty($postData)){
            $postData = base64_decode($postData, 'UTF-8');
... more code unrelated
```

When I do `print_r($postData)` I see that it gets correctly decoded but the thing is, that base64 returns a string and I need either an array or JSON. I've looked around the site and the docs and I saw this: [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and this question before: [PHP: Good way to reconstruct associative array from base64_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772407/php-good-way-to-reconstruct-associative-array-from-base64-decode) but upon trying those answers or what I've found I still can't reconstruct the array.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I forgot to add my decoded data (`print_r($postData)`). It looks like so:

```
{
id_evento: "105",
eventDescription: "Evento Nuevo",
eventTotal: "120000",
fechaEvento: "2020-05-20",
tipoPago: "Tarjeta",
nombre: "Bob",
apellido: "Ross",
email: "bob@ross.com",
tel: "1234567890",
bday: "01/05/2020",
descuento: "",
stripeToken: "tok_1Gi"
}
```

The thing is, that it is now (after being decoded) a string.

Comment: What does `$postData` look like *after* decoding?

Comment: added it. Sorry! @Nick

Comment: That looks like a JS object, which can't be directly decoded in PHP. I would suggest sending the output of `JSON.stringify` on your object instead; then you will be able to use `json_decode` directly in PHP.

Comment: @Nick I am doing `var form_data = JSON.stringify($("#payment-form").serializeObject());
form_data = b64EncodeUnicode(form_data);`then sending it via ajax. Would the same approach work?

Comment: @Nick, this was it! Could you make it an answer to select it?

Comment: Were you already using `JSON.stringify`? I'm surprised your string didn't look like JSON already (object names enclosed in double quotes)